# LULC can't encode object in GEE for different sources

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to get a LULC map for different periods. I am trying to check the differences year by year but I am getting the following error:

> Random Forest Classification 2018: Layer error: Can't encode object: function(a){return Array.isArray(this.ca)?gu(Yu(a,this.ca)):Wx.fb.aa.call(this,a)}

Honestly, I do not know what that means and it is followed by:

> Random Forest Classification 2018: Layer error: Image.visualize: The values of field 'palette' must be strings.

This is the classification part:

```js
// Define el clasificador de Random Forest
var randomForestClassifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest({
  numberOfTrees: numberOfTrees,
  variablesPerSplit: variablesPerSplit,
  minLeafPopulation: minLeafPopulation,
  bagFraction: bagFraction,
  maxNodes: maxNodes,
  seed: seed
});

// Entrena el clasificador de Random Forest
var randomForestClassifierTrained = randomForestClassifier.train(trainSet, label, bands);

// Clasifica la imagen de entrada utilizando el clasificador de Random Forest
var classifiedRandomForest = input.classify(randomForestClassifierTrained);
```

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

https://code.earthengine.google.co.in/1f6c9278e429e7d1709812713549078f?accept_repo=users%2Fujavalgandhi%2FGEE-Dynamic-World

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `Map.addLayer`, the palette needs to be a client-side list of strings. Both of your errors are coming from invalid palettes.

> Random Forest Classification 2018: Layer error: Can't encode object: function(a){return Array.isArray(this.ca)?gu(Yu(a,this.ca)):Wx.fb.aa.call(this,a)}

This is caused by converting your palette to an `ee.List` on line 95. You can get rid of `landcoverPaletteStrings` and just use `landcoverPalette`.

> Random Forest Classification 2018: Layer error: Image.visualize: The values of field 'palette' must be strings.

On line 170, you redefine `landcoverPalette` as a **list of lists** of strings in order to build your legend. That makes it invalid for use with `Map.addLayer`. Instead, I'd recommend keeping the unchanged `landcoverPalette` and renaming the list of lists that you use for the legend.

Another option if you don't want to define your palette twice is to use an `Object` like so:

```js
// Palette with the colors and names
var landcoverPalette = {
  '253494': 'Water', // Azul oscuro
  '969696': 'Buildup', // Gris
  'ffffff': 'Snow', // Blanco
  '238b45': 'Vegetation', // Verde oscuro
  'a1d99b': 'Agriculture', // Verde claro
}
```

When you use it in `Map.addLayer`, you can get the list of colors with `Object.keys(landcoverPalette)`.

```js
Map.addLayer(classifiedRandomForest, {min: 1, max: 6, palette: Object.keys(landcoverPalette)}, 'Random Forest Classification 2018');
```

When you use it to build the legend, you can iterate over the colors (keys) and use them to get the associated names:

```js
// Add color and and names
Object.keys(landcoverPalette).forEach(function(color) {
  var name = landcoverPalette[color];
  legend.add(makeRow(color, name));
})
```

Comment: Thanks so much!